# Output random string stored in array

Tags: php, arrays, string, random, echo

Hello once again stackoverflow. I've been working on something in PHP. Now, what I require is that PHP picks a random value in my array I have and outputs it. But, not make it the same every time, constantly change it everytime the page is loaded.

What I have so far:

```
    <?php
$a=array("Value 1", "Value 2", "Value 3", "Value 4", "Value 5");
$random_keys=array_rand($a);
echo $random_keys;
?>
```

Now, I've tried this script but it outputs numbers instead of a value. What is it exactly I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do:

```
<?php
$a=array("Value 1", "Value 2", "Value 3", "Value 4", "Value 5");
$random_keys=array_rand($a);
echo $a[$random_keys];
```

array_rand returns the key not the value. You will need to use the key to return the value like above.

Comment: Thank you so much! I now see what you mean. Worked perfectly!

Comment: @NomadsBoy You are welcome. If you feel that the answer helped you, you can always mark it as the answer. It should help others as well.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you could also use the function shuffle(), which re-orders the original array.

```
$a=array("Value 1", "Value 2", "Value 3", "Value 4", "Value 5");
shuffle($a);
echo $a[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

It returns the Index so you should write:

```
$random_keys=$a[array_rand($a)];
echo $random_keys;
```